# Node electron app - Permiso denegado Para webcam

Tags: javascript, nodejs, electron

Holas. Tengo un problema al ejecutar electron con nodeJs. Dentro de electron tengo en la vista código JS `script SRC = jsFile.js` que me muestra la webcam. Si lo corro en el navegador en localhost:3000, todo bien pero si ejecuto en electron me muestra error. Permiso denegado de la cámara:

NotAllowed.

Como se puede solucionar el permiso dentro del electrón?

Edit:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor leer [ask] y [mcve]. El código relevante y los mensajes de error deben ir en formato texto y no en imagen. Saludos

Comment: para que la camara funciones, la pagina tiene que estar bajo https para que la funcionalidad de la camara funciones

Comment: Gracias probaré a ver ...

Comment: @tecnobyte eso es cierto, pero no son las unicas opciones validas, tecnicamente es valido cualquier tipo de protocolo que sea seguro, por ejemplo, 127.0.0.1, tambien es seguro, localhost y el protocolo https. protocolos como http o acceder directamente mediante una IP a localhost se consideran inseguros.

Comment: @Riven . Corriendo en 127.0.0.1 Me muestra el error en electron

Comment: No recuerdo exactamente la configuracion para la 127.0.0.1, pero a mi me funcionaba en esa direccion, de todas maneras esa direccion seria inutil para usarla de manera remota (solo sirve de manera local), asi que 127.0.0.1 tampoco seria tu solucion.